# Error creating bean, Injection of autowired dependencies failed - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations, project, spring-annotations

I have created a new Spring project and I have some trouble when I run the application. I am new to Spring development and I thing that the annotations are not placed properly. Any detailed explanation would be great for me for better understating. I am currently reading Spring in action, but if any other book or tutorial seems more accurate, please leave me a comment :)[[this is the error that I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSPRY.png) - 500 Internal Server Error].

This is my project:

**HelloWorldConfiguration**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;


@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")


public class HelloWorldConfiguration {

    @Bean(name="HelloWorld")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**HelloWordInitializer**

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class HelloWorldInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(HelloWorldConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

**HelloWorldController**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import service.StudentService;


import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@Controller
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websystique.springmvc")
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloWorldController {

    public HelloWorldController(){

    }

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;

    private Map<String, Student> persoaneAdaugate = new HashMap<String, Student>();

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHello(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloagain", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String sayHelloAgain(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Hello World Again, from Spring 4 MVC");
        return "welcome";
    }


    /***
     * @ModelAttribute = binds a method parameter or a method return value to a named model attribute and then exposes it to a web view.
     * @param student
     * @param result
     * @param modelMap
     * @return
     * That is, @ModelAttribute methods are invoked before the controller methods annotated with @RequestMapping are invoked.
     * The logic behind the sequence is that, the model object has to be created before any processing starts inside the controller methods.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("addStudent") Student student, BindingResult result, ModelMap modelMap){
        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "error";
        }
        else {
         studentService.addStudent(student);
        }
        /*modelMap.addAttribute("nume", student.getNume());
        modelMap.addAttribute("prenume", student.getPrenume());
        persoaneAdaugate.put(student.getNume(), student);
        System.out.println("Persoane adaugate: " + persoaneAdaugate +"\n");
        System.out.println("nume: " + student.getNume()+" si prenume: " +student.getPrenume());
*/
        return "success";
    }

}
```

**StudentDao**

```
import com.websystique.springmvc.model.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.List;
@Component
public interface StudentDao {
    List<Student> getAllStudents();
    void addStudent(Student student);
}
```

**StudentDaoImpl**

```
import com.websystique.springmvc.model.Student;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Repository("studentDao")
@Service
@Transactional

public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{


    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return null;
       // return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Date").list();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(student);
    }
}
```

**Student**

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name="DATE")

public class Student implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="nume", unique=true, nullable=false )
    private String nume;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="prenume", nullable = false)
    private String prenume;

    protected Student(){

    }

    Student(String nume, String prenume){
        this.prenume=prenume;
        this.nume=nume;
    }
    public String getNume(){
        return nume;
    }
    public void setNume(String nume){
        this.nume=nume;
    }

    public String getPrenume(){
        return prenume;
    }

    public void setPrenume(String prenume){
        this.prenume=prenume;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return "Numele adaugat: nume= " + nume +" si prenume= " +prenume;
    }

}
```

**StudentService**

```
import com.websystique.springmvc.model.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import java.util.List;

@Component
public interface StudentService {
    List<Student> getAllStudents();

     void addStudent(Student student);

}
```

**StudentServiceImpl**

```
import com.websystique.springmvc.dao.StudentDao;
import com.websystique.springmvc.model.Student;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;
@Service
@Transactional
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentDao studentDao;

    @Transactional
    public List<Student> getAllStudents() {
        return studentDao.getAllStudents();
    }

    public void addStudent(Student student) {
        studentDao.addStudent(student);
    }

}
```

Comment: I used [this](https://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) link to setup the spring mvc application. This is a step by step guide.

Comment: Thank you a lot:) I will look into this today